# Couldn't find Person with 'login'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I never developed anything for web before, but now I have to make a simple application to show some data from an existing database.

Thing is, each user should only see his/her respective data, so I need some form of authentication to do querys joining that user and other tables. I tried to keep things simple, all the user have to do is type it's username, which is the primary key on the Pessoa table (no passwords, no email confirmation, no nothing).

I've read a few tutorials about Rails on RailsGuides, and www.rubypigeon.com/posts/how-to-implement-simple-authentication-without-devise/ for the authentication, but I just can't get my login to work.

Here's my code so far:

HomeController:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def login
    @user = Pessoa.new
  end

  def sign_in
    @user = Pessoa.find(params[:id])

    if @user
      session.clear
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      render '/'
    else
      @error = 'Username or password was incorrect'
      erb :sign_in
    end
  end

  def sign_out
    session.clear
    render '/'
  end

  helper_method :current_user
  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      Pessoa.find (session[:user_id])
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

views/home/login.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: home_sign_in_path do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :"digite seu login" %>
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit :entrar %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  get 'home/index'

  get 'home/login', to: 'home#login'
  post 'home/sign_in', to: 'home#sign_in'
  post 'home/sign_out', to: 'home#sign_out' 

  resources :pessoas
end
```

/views/home/index.html.erb have a lot of static HTML stuff, the only Ruby code on it is a

```
<%= link_to 'Login', home_login_path %>
```

Pessoa.rb

```
class Pessoa < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'pessoa'
  self.primary_key = 'login'
end
```

I'm working with legacy tables on PostgreSQL, that's why primary key had to be changed.

Whenever I go to localhost:3000/home/login and type my login, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eE3i.png)
error message. The weird part is if I run the exact same line that gives me the error on the console, it works just fine.

As I said, I'm very new to Rails and web development in general, so I think it's a tiny detail that I aparently can't see. Any help would be appreciated.

Btw, don't mind the resource name, "Pessoa" means "Person" in portuguese, which is my native language.

development.log:

```
Started GET "/home/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 20:22:45 -0300
Processing by HomeController#login as HTML
  Rendering home/login.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/login.html.erb within layouts/application (12.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1504ms (Views: 1369.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/home/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 20:22:50 -0300
Processing by HomeController#sign_in as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Jzt0Yeven91Kl8DrfjpJa8I9PJjr7SzKmE43lwprjlopV7l+zFU6EUjUgAiKYJhzemm7xu8NGfiPj3E5h5EiYw==", "pessoa"=>{"id"=>"gabrielbrito"}, "commit"=>"entrar"}
  [1m[36mPessoa Load (1.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "pessoa".* FROM "pessoa" WHERE "pessoa"."login" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["login", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Pessoa with 'login'=):

app/controllers/home_controller.rb:10:in `sign_in'
Started PUT "/__web_console/repl_sessions/ed3bb60f3a72a0c0b0c951fa03c0f23d" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 20:22:56 -0300
Started PUT "/__web_console/repl_sessions/ed3bb60f3a72a0c0b0c951fa03c0f23d" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 20:22:58 -0300
Started PUT "/__web_console/repl_sessions/ed3bb60f3a72a0c0b0c951fa03c0f23d" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 20:23:04 -0300
[1m[36mPessoa Load (1.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "pessoa".* FROM "pessoa" WHERE "pessoa"."login" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["login", "gabrielbrito"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Started GET "/home/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 21:27:45 -0300
Processing by HomeController#login as HTML
  Rendering home/login.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/login.html.erb within layouts/application (6.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1626ms (Views: 1152.5ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)


Started POST "/home/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 21:27:52 -0300
Processing by HomeController#sign_in as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"q2ffWM1gqaXfCrsFm7KlGKwR/iTDoQBflquem2BKSaeMyKBiIaUrtnIkoEXNztUWRasIGGg0qZZxpdYao8xb9Q==", "pessoa"=>{"id"=>"gabrielbrito"}, "commit"=>"entrar"}
  [1m[36mPessoa Load (2.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "pessoa".* FROM "pessoa" WHERE "pessoa"."login" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["login", "gabrielbrito"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)


NoMethodError (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/home_controller.rb:15:in `sign_in'
```

**EDIT:** Solved, thanks to @Gerry's help.

Comment: The error and your controller are different, that is, your code has `@user = Pessoa.find(params[:id])` but the error says `@user = Pessoa.find(params[:pessoa][:id])`. Do the current code also gives you an error?

Comment: Can you show the output in your console/logs?

Comment: My bad, I tried `@user = Pessoafind(params[:id])` before, but typing that on the console gave me nil, so I changed it to `@user = Pessoa.find(params[:pessoa][:id])`, New code gives me the same error, even though the console shows me the record from the table.
EDIT: updated with log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It seems to be an issue with `self.primary_key = 'login'` in your model, so try adding that key to your routes:

```
resources :pessoas, param: :login
```

To be consistent, you should also change any reference of `id` to `login`, that is, in your controller:

```
@user = Pessoa.find_by(login: params[:pessoa][:login])
```

And in your view:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :"digite seu login" %>
  <%= f.text_field :login %>
</div>
```

---

Regarding

> "undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass" on line render '/'

You should change `render '/'` to either a `redirect_to` (to redirect to another page) or `render view_name` where `view_name` is the name of the view you want to render.

For example, if you want to redirect to home, you could do this:

```
redirect_to home_path
```

---

Also, you should use `find_by` instead of `find` to avoid getting the same error when a user enters an invalid `login` (i.e. one that does not exist in DB):

```
@user = Pessoa.find_by(login: params[:pessoa][:login])
```

Since this way you will get an empty collection instead of an error (exception), you will also need to update how you evaluate if a `User` was found:

```
if @user.present?
  # success code
else
  # failure code
end
```

Putting it all together, your `sign_in` action should look like this:

```
def sign_in
  @user = Pessoa.find_by(login: params[:pessoa][:login])

  if @user.present?
    session.clear
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    @error = 'Username or password was incorrect'
  end
end
```

Comment: Same error, and typing the new find_by shows the same output on console. It feels like the params from the form are not carrying over to the view, somehow.

Comment: Well, that's some progress. Now it says "undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass" on line `render '/'`

Comment: @GabrielEugenio Ohh, missed it. I guess you want the user to be redirected to home, correct? If so, you must use `redirect_to` instead of `render`. Otherwise use the name of the view to be rendered instead of `/`.

Comment: Hm... tried using `redirect_to home_index_path`, `redirect_to root_path` and `render :index`, but still have the "undefined method 'empty?'" message

Comment: @GabrielEugenio Could you post the complete log for that error?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to save all files I modified while changing the "[:id]" from controller and views. It's working now. Thank you.